# Permission Denied with Docker-Compose on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I am currently learning Docker, with the book "Using Docker". In chapter 5, the author switches from using `docker run` to using `docker compose`, which yields a `permission denied` error in my test application. Is there something I can do to have it work?

I use:

- Windows 10 Home Edition, with the Docker Toolbox
- Docker version is `1.12.0`
- Docker Compose version is `1.8.0`, build `d988a55`

*DockerFile*:

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN groupadd -r uwsgi && useradd -r -g uwsgi uwsgi
RUN pip install Flask==0.10.1 uWSGI==2.0.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app
COPY cmd.sh /

EXPOSE 9090 9191
USER uwsgi

CMD ["/cmd.sh"]
```

*docker-compose.yml*:

```
identidock:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  environment:
    ENV: DEV
  volumes:
    - ./app:/app
```

The application is located under `C:/Users/MyUserName`, as required by the Toolbox, to have shared volumes working correctly.

The working docker command, which starts the container and the web server, exposing it successfully to my Windows host:

```
docker run -e "ENV=DEV" -p 5000:5000 identidock
```

The `docker-compose up` command fails with the following message:

```
Starting identidock_identidock_1

ERROR: for identidock  Cannot start service identidock: oci runtime error: exec: "/cmd.sh": permission denied
←[31mERROR←[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Will you try running it as administrator?

Comment: @RafafTahsin Hello. You mean, running the Docker Quickstart Terminal as an admin? I've just tried, same issue.

Comment: execute your console in administrator mode then this commande docker-compose up from ex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding

```
RUN chmod +x /cmd.sh
```

to your Dockerfile after

```
COPY cmd.sh /
```

According to [that issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3065) it seems that the docker client sets the needed exec permission for the file while docker compose does not

> It may be that the docker client sets the executable bit for all
>   files, where as Compose does not (yet).

Comment: Cheers, this works! Note to other beginners like me: make sure to force an image rebuild to have this work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to run the command line (git bash) as administrator then run again :

```
docker-compose up -d .
```

this worked for me.